# Pointing to a cell address given in string format

Tags: vba

I have cell addresses given in an excel sheet and wanted to print a specific formula in other excel sheet referring to the cell addresses given in the previous sheet. Please suggest vba function for this. The cell addresses are in string format so corresponding row no. and col. no need to be extracted from the string. Is there an existing function for this in vba?

Comment: An example of your string would help.

Comment: Eg. G2 is mentioned ( text format) in cell A1 of Sheet 1. I want to go to G2 cell of Sheet 2 and print the value of cell A2 of Sheet 1.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will check for last row in sheet1 column A and try to get values present in odd rows in column A and print the result in even row numbers

```
Sub testt1()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet2")


Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


On Error Resume Next


For i = 1 To lastRow

t1 = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value


t2 = ws2.Range(t1).Value

ws1.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = t2

i = i + 1

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Could you tell which format you will get input i mean cell address

Comment: Hi I think I haven't explained the problem clearly.  "G2" is mentioned ( text format) in cell A1 of Sheet 1. I want to go to G2 cell of Sheet 2 and print the value of cell A2 of Sheet 1. Basically I want to run a macro because in Sheet 1 I have several cell addresses given in text format and I want to print certain values in those cell addresses of Sheet2 which are equal to the cell addresses ( in text format) given in Sheet1

Comment: If Sheet1 contains  A1 = G2 , Then you want to go Sheet2 G2 cell and print  Sheet1 A2 value in Sheet2 G2 . Am i Right

Comment: Then your values will be present only in A column? one after another like A1, A3, A5 and you want to prrint the values of A2, A4, A6 in sheet2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but the Range method accepts string input. For your example, this would work:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value)=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
```

Same code, a bit easier on the eyes:

```
Dim strLocation As String
strLocation = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strLocation) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
```

Is this what you are looking to do? Do you need more help understanding it?

Comment: I was able to print the required values using range function. Thanks newjenn.